# vertical alignment is never responding

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

vertical-align is the one issue which i am struggling to fix for long days. I understand vertical-align css property is [buggy](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align) in most of the browsers.

Mostly, we can fix using display:table-cell, because vertical-align is ideal for table and IE will not respond for this.

But, do we have any other alternate fix for vertical-alignment.

Here, is my example for which i suppose to fix.
http://jsfiddle.net/gviswanathan/5rVJ3/

[image: Suppose to be like this]

Comment: OK, so what exactly are you trying to fix?

Comment: IE8 and above are fine with the `table-cell` value. Edit unrelated to uyour question: "Title" shouldn't be a division (div) but a heading (h1 if there isn't one already, or another hN)

Comment: Yes true, but what uploaded in jsfiddle is not working any browsers

Comment: @gviswanathan given the fiddle which might achieve what you want,increase the `line-height` to which ever length you want to align it to the bottom...

Comment: @gviswanathan if your new to stackoverflow,learn to accept an answer that best suits your need or fixes your problem.. its as important as asking a question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `line-height` would be a good replacement.. but,it depends on what you are applying it on.. it will work in your case though.. check the fiddle,added `height,width,line-height`

http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/R4Y4s/2/

Comment: Exactly, but this is something like component. Title can be replaced with anything. So, i it cannot be fixed by the fixed height or line-height.

Comment: @gviswanathan if its a div/component,then `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` should fix your problem.. then again,depends on what you are applying on.. it you tell me what you are trying to work on -- to get alignment,i can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bottom-margin in div blocks in case vertical-align doesn help to achieve your required result.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: ?px">
```

where ? can be +ve or -ve value as necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with a negative bottom margin on the ul. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5rVJ3/13/

code that changed:

```
.w ul, .w li {
    list-style : none;
    margin: 0 0 -7px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that article cannot be taken seriously.